# How to delete zookeeper session ID from the client

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a script where we restore zookeeper data and before starting this script we stop the client services and the zookeeper. Then we run a python script and restore the data and then start all services again. Once this is done few of services written in python are having trouble connecting to zookeeper and upon analysing the logs I can see this error

`Refusing session request for client /<ip>:<dynamic port> as it has seen zxid 0x500000186 our last zxid is 0x4000006a3 client must try another server`

A simple a restart of docker container solve the problem.

My theory is that the client is attempting a connection with an old transaction id and session id and zookeeper rejects that connection. And the ideal way to solve this would be to implement a logic to clear the session id from the client in the execution of the script before starting the container. The only problem is I cannot seem to figure out a way of clearing the old session id.

EDIT:

When I am doing docker stop and docker restart for the service; it clears the session ID and transaction ID of zookeeper from the client and the client is starting the connection as a fresh one properly. However, when I do systemctl restart the IDs are not being cleared properly and the connection to zookeeper is refused mentioning the above error. I suspect this is because both these commands are sending different SIGNALS to process. but in order to fix this I need to understand how and where is the session ID and transaction ID is stored so I can clear it. Let me know if more info is required

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.